# How to avoid downcasting in entity component system c++

Tags: c++

I recently came across the Entity Component System that is frequently used in game engines. I decided to implement it myself in C++, but quickly ran into a familiar problem. It all began innocent enough. I started with the following classes:

```
class Entity
{
    private:
        int entityId;
        std::map<std::string, Component*> components;

    public:
        Entity();
        ~Entity();

        void AddComponent(Component *component);
        void RemoveComponent(std::string name);
        bool HasComponent(std::string name);
        Component* GetComponent(std::string name);
};


class Component
{
    public:
        int componentId;

};
```

I then decided to create some specific component types:

```
class Input : public Component
{
    public:
        void process();
}

class Physics : public Component
{
    public:
        void update();
}
```

I began to test this out. I created an entity:

```
Entity *entity = new Entity();
entity->AddComponent(new Input());
entity->AddComponent(new Physics());
```

This is where things started going wrong though. I then thought about how I would get components from an entity. What if I wanted to do something like:

```
Physics *physics = entity->GetComponent("Physics");
physics->update();
```

But GetComponent("Physics") returns the base class Component, not the derived class Physics! I did some searching on the internet but couldn't find an example in c++ that showed how to get around this problem. After taking a look at what Unity does, I discovered that they seem to just perform a down cast. For example in Unity the code (C#) would be:

```
Physics physics = entity.GetComponent("Physics") as Physics;
```

Isn't this down cast bad? How does one get around this in C++ when designing an Entity Component System? Or how does one perform the downcast?

Comment: Perhaps use the same function name for both `process` and `update`, and make it a pure virtual function in the `Component` class to be overridden by the child classes? You *do* know about `virtual` functions? It's a vital part of C++ inheritance and polymorphism.

Comment: Yes but this is a simple example. What if I have 100 different component types, each with dozens of different methods. Component would then have to have 100's of virtual methods.

Comment: Probably the goal is achievable if `GetComponent` declared as template method `T GetComponent<T>(const std::string& name)`. Slightly boring but allows to hide all the gory details within the method

Comment: @James I'd probably go for a design to query for and access certain interface types (pure abstract classes) similar like COM interfaces.

Comment: @user3159253 So I thought about that but then I got stuck on how to store the components in the Entity class. For example, how would the AddComponent<T> method be implemented?

Comment: Casting/virtual calls in C# are implemented totally different from C++. It essentially employs self-modifying code which adapts at run time, thus hiding the extra indirection after just a few iterations.

Comment: @James All in all it seems your question is a bit too broad. There are many patterns that can be deployed to approach this problem. It seems your question is a better fit for [SE Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Perhaps you should research the *visitor pattern*?

Comment: Or perhaps a redesign might be in order? For better shared commonality and better interfaces (i.e. the public member functions)?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I think you're missing the point of ECS.

Comment: @James Why would your components have dozens of different methods? Each component should have exactly one method that is used to update it in each iteration, the 'update' method, any other methods it might need aren't ones that need to be accessible through the Component interface and so aren't ones that need to be virtual.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The components that make up an entity are keyed on their type. If an ECS makes you write `entity.get("Foo") as Foo` then that's already a design weakness; it should make you write `entity.get<Foo>()`.

In C++, you could write the code like this:

```
class Entity {
  std::unordered_map<std::type_index, std::unique_ptr<Component>> components;

public:
  template <typename C>
  void AddComponent(std::unique_ptr<C> p) {
    // can't remember if unique_ptr allows this conversion
    components[typeid(C)] = std::move(p);
  }

  template <typename C>
  C& GetComponent() {
    // You *know* this cast has to work. You should handle null here though.
    return *static_cast<C*>(components[typeid(C)].get());
  }
};
```

Though note that it is rather unusual for an entity to hold its components *at all*. Usually you have a world, and it holds all components. An entity merely keys into the world's collection of components.

When your world has all components, then you can give it one collection per component type. (Indeed, that is a favored representation, since it often gives you better memory access patterns.) Then you don't need an abstract base class for your components anymore.

Comment: +1 I haven't gotten a chance to try `typeid` (my ECS has to revolve around info at runtime and sometimes even scripts). Do you know if `typeid` could be portably used across module boundaries and different compilers, like if one person using a dylib made with GCC would get the same ID for `typeid(Foo)` as another dylib built against, say, ICC? I've always had to roll my own `typeid`-like solutions in the past but wouldn't have to in some cases if it was portable in this way.

Comment: @DrunkCoder As the C++ standard doesn't say anything about module boundaries, I would say it's risky. The Common C++ ABI does specify the result of `typeid`, but I *know* that there have been issues in the past with Clang/G++ interoperability.

Comment: Ah shucks, I was hoping maybe they rectified it by C++11. I always found some nice use cases for `typeid`-like solutions, but in the past I had to roll my own one due to having to support modules built against different compilers and it wasn't nearly as nice to use as just `typeid` itself.

Comment: @SebastianRedl Thanks you this is exactly what I was looking for. In my case I actually don't add the components to my entities, but rather decided to add them to a static map in the Entity class. This way I can access them in my render system etc like for(it = Entity::components.begin(); it != Entity::components.end(); it++) etc. Does this seem reasonable in regards to what you talked about in your last two paragraphs?

Answer (score 2):

ECS revolves around casting and duck typing. But you can use a `dynamic_cast` for safety if you want (possibly just for debug builds), and hide it from the client so that you get this type of syntax:

```
Physics* physics = entity->get<Physics>();
```

And you got more safety than I do! Mine is implemented in C and provided through a C API to be used through plugins and scripts, so I have to actually cast from void pointers (but just in one central place).

It tends to not be a big deal in practice since the client code tends to ensure the integrity of what's going on since they're expressing the component type they want to retrieve. In C++ you can even do static checks at compile-time to make sure they are retrieving an actual component type and not some other type. I wouldn't recommend having them specify strings as you have though, since then a typo wouldn't lead to any type of compile-time error.

COM as used in DirectX also revolves around these casts to retrieve an interface. When it's unified through an interface query as in COM or a component query as in ECS, then it tends to not be a big deal in practice (people don't trip up over it as with a codebase that downcasts things sporadically with deep inheritance hierarchies).

A lot of the traditional practices revolving around OOP don't necessarily apply to ECS since it's such a radically different way of approaching architectures. For example, established OOP practices tend to strongly encourage information hiding, discourage downcasts, and SOLID suggests that dependencies flow towards abstractions.

Well, in an ECS, we have downcasts to retrieve components (but it's unified), we have components just exposing their data in raw form (but not a big deal since only a few systems access this data, so the scope of the data is narrow), and dependencies flow towards data, not abstractions (but somehow the design is much easier to keep stable anyway in at least game or game-like domains due to its enormous flexibility).

[image]

> Or how does one perform the downcast?

One way is to store the key used to fetch the component as part of the component type, like:

```
struct Physics
{
    enum {id = ...};
};
```

Then you can do like:

```
template <class Component>
Component* Entity::get()
{
     const int id = Component::id;
     // Find for the component from the id.
     return component_ptr;
}
```

... or as `Sebastian Redl` points out, you can just use `typeid` (I forgot how to do this all statically due to that C API, since I have scripters and plugins adding new component types on the fly).